# how to build a baseline var without building 2nd data set

Tags: r

I have df that I could like to calculate the baseline score for each ID. I know I can get build a subset with baseline score then merge back to `df`, but I feel it is a silly way. Is there a way to build my baseline without doing two data set?
[image]

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Score = c(97, 96, 
58, 96, 35, 45, 89), Date = c(20210110, 20210109, 20210108, 20210107, 
20210106, 20210105, 20210104)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Add a column? How do the baseline values link with df?

Comment: baseline value is the score with earliest date.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Baseline = Score[which.min(Date)])`

Answer (score 1):

You can group by ID, then take the Score that corresponds to the minimum Date within each group:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    group_split(ID) %>% 
    map(., function(df){
           df %>%  mutate(Baseline = df$Score[df$Date == min(df$Date)])
    }) %>% bind_rows()
```

Gives

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID Score     Date Baseline
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1    97 20210110       96
2     1    96 20210109       96
3     2    58 20210108       96
4     2    96 20210107       96
5     3    35 20210106       89
6     3    45 20210105       89
7     3    89 20210104       89
```